# What is wrong with my create table query?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create table users, but I get an error. My code is:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT_NULL,
    email varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT_NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT_NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The error is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
    email varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT_NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT_NULL,
...' at line 2
```

Comment: `NOT_NULL` is not valid syntax, try to use `NOT NULL`

Comment: oh right, thanks ! it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `NOT NULL` rather than `NOT_NULL`

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    email varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```